# my program to insert data in linked list is not working

Tags: c, singly-linked-list

The following code is not working. The linked list uses a structure called node that has two fields `int data`, and `struct node* next`. I defined two head nodes, `struct node* head1` and `struct node* head2` globally.

```
void insert(struct node* h, int data)  //h is the head node
{
    struct node* temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    temp->data=data;
    temp->next=NULL;

    if(h==NULL)
    {
      h=temp;   
    }
    else
    {
      struct node* ptr=h;

      while(ptr->next!=NULL)
      {
        ptr=ptr->next; 
      }

      ptr->next=temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: The argument variable `h` is a *local variable* inside the function `insert`. As such all changes to it will be lost once the life-time of the variable ends when the function returns. I suggest you do some research about *emulating pass by reference in C*.

Comment: Don't typecast `malloc` and the logic seems to be correct in this part where `h` is not null - can help only if complete code is provided.

Comment: You are supposed to give a [mcve]. This is not one. A a wild guess the problem could come from ` if(h==NULL)

{

 h=temp;

 }` which only assigns to the local copy: the passed pointer remains unchanged.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Changes will be lost only when `h` is `null` and being used to point it to `temp`?

Comment: @Observer Yes that's true, but the chances that `h` will ever become non-null with this code is slim to none.

Answer (score 1):

Your `h` is local to `insert` and will be destroyed once control exits `insert` function.
Also any changes done to `h` inside `insert` will not affect the original head.

**Solution:**

You can pass the reference of original head to `insert` in order to retain changes made in `insert` as below.

```
   void insert(struct node **h, int data)  //h is the head node
    {
         struct node* temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
         temp->data=data;
         temp->next=NULL;

         if(*h == NULL)
         {
            *h=temp;
         }
         else
         {
            struct node* ptr = *h;
            while(ptr->next!=NULL)
            {
                ptr=ptr->next;
            }
            ptr->next=temp;
       }
    }
```

and you call `insert` as below.

```
struct node *head = NULL;
insert(&head,1);
```